# How do substances for gene expression work?

Tags: gene-expression

How does amplification of gene expression work?
I often find in various articles expressions like "Using substance X or peptide X, we enhanced the expression of gene Z, which led to a certain therapeutic effect.

How to find out which substance enhances the expression of a particular gene? Is there a law, a pattern for this, or, if all this is found out empirically, a summary table of expressing substances?

Comment: Try being more specific; Gene regulation is a very broad topic, with lots of intricate mechanisms. Where did you here this? What substances did they use, and for which gene?